# Hacking cacheAsBitmap for flash player 7

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a dynamically generated MovieClip that nests many MovieClips and it's a bit jerky when I drag it. The project requires using flash player 7. I would like to use the cacheAsBitmap property but it was not available until flash player 8.  Does anyone know of a means of approximating the cachAsBitmap functionality using flash player 7 capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't really possible in flash player 7. You only have 3 main options:

- Simplify/optimise your graphics so they don't lag when you drag it
- Push to get to flash player 8, or at least flash player 9 (where you can use Bitmap, Sprite, Shape etc). Flash player 10.1 speed improvements. Is this for an internal network where they all use IE6 and never update?
- Precreate your graphics in something like Photoshop and move them as an image. You can keep the separate MovieClips if you need to animate etc, just swap in the image when you're dragging

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'll have to live with it as is until the Flash player for these systems is updated.